# How I can get the date this week between Monday and Sunday AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**How I can get the date this week between Monday and Sunday**

Example the date between , this week is : Monday = 23/11/2015 to Sunday 29/11/2015 I want to get dates every week, between Monday and Sunday

AngujarJS , JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *vanilla* you could set the day of the week on a *Date* instance like this,

```
function setDay(d, day, week_starts_monday) {
    var c_day = d.getDay();
    if (week_starts_monday && c_day === 0)
        c_day = 7; // adjust so `0` is last week sunday, 7 is this week sunday
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - c_day + day);
    return d;
}
```

So, the Monday of this week would be *(today being Friday 27th)*

```
var d = new Date;
setDay(d, 1); // Mon Nov 23 2015 18:51:45 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

**`7` is the next Sunday**. `0` is the previous Sunday (or the current day if it is Sunday).

```
setDay(d, 7); // Sun Nov 29 2015 18:51:45 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

You can now iterate as desired with `for`,

```
var i, d = new Date;
for (i = 1; i <= 7; ++i) {
    setDay(d, i);
    // do something with `d`
}
```

Please note

- Crossing timezones may cause unexpected results. Maybe you'll want to do this in UTC?
- If you wish to go backwards from *Sunday* you will need to use negative numbers.

Comment: that is okat but how I can do in angular ,

Comment: Angular is a framework, you still have all of vanilla

Comment: Hello Paul , I have a little problem this Sunday 6 algorithm you gave me will change the date 2015/12/7 - 2015/12/13, is so has to change but do not want to change on Sunday, I want to change Monday

Comment: @LuisAlvarez pass `true` as the 3rd param (`week_starts_monday`). _Sunday_ of the _current week_ is now index `7`